# Merge table after a group without _time

Tags: influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

Hello i'm trying to have a graph who give me the mean value of a time series by hour during x Days

I've succeeded to have the mean value but now all value are in different table and i don't know how to merge the table.

I've seen merge or union function but i don't understand how to use them in a pipe

```
import "date"

from(bucket: "myBucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "°C")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["someField"] == "aValue")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with hour: date.hour(t: r._time)}))
  |> group(columns: ["hour"])
  |> mean()
```

My goal is to have all value in the same table and have a graph not just dot in influxd dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [aggregateWindow](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/aggregatewindow/), I believe it does what you are trying to achieve.

```js
from(bucket: "myBucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "°C")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["someField"] == "aValue")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean)
```